# next level button gives unknown error in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I've a gameviewcontroller which gets 2 values from 1st view controller .. i.e. **selectedlevelnumber** and **nextlevelnumber**. I want to show Next Level button when current level is completed. So next level button is showing when level is completed but when clicking on next level button it gives me unknown error, console says **lldb** and takes me to AppDelegate.swift. 
I have this code in my GameViewController

```
if levelisCompleted == true {
LevelCompletedView().levelcomplete(selectedlevelnumber, nextlevel: nextlevelnumber)
} .. this is working perfectly
```

now this is my LevelCompletedView

```
class LevelCompletedView: UIViewController {

    func levelcomplete(levelnum:String, nextlevel:String) {

        println("\(levelnum) is completed ")
        println("next level is \(nextlevel)")

        var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 50)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle("Next Level", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonA:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        gamesubView.addSubview(button)


        func buttonA(sender:UIButton!) {
            println("loading next level \(nextlevel)")
            let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var gameview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("gamevc") as GameViewController
            gameview.levelSelectedNum = String(nextlevel)

            self.presentViewController(gameview, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

everything works, only the button is not working when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now, the `buttonA:` method is local since it's contained within `levelComplete`, so once `levelComplete` has finished executing, the `buttonA:` function disappears. Your button's not recognizing it's target action `buttonA:` because it wasn't defined within the scope of its class -- thus the resulting error. Move `func buttonA` outside of `levelComplete` to correct this issue.

And to access `nextlevel`, save it as a global variables, ex.

```
class LevelCompletedView: UIViewController {

    var nextLevelVar:String!

    func levelcomplete(levelnum:String, nextlevel:String) {

        println("\(levelnum) is completed ")
        println("next level is \(nextlevel)")

        nextLevelVar = nextlevel

        var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 50)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle("Next Level", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonA:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        gamesubView.addSubview(button)

    }

    func buttonA(sender:UIButton!) {
        println("loading next level \(nextLevelVar)")
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var gameview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("gamevc") as GameViewController
        gameview.levelSelectedNum = String(nextLevelVar)

        self.presentViewController(gameview, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: that sounds correct but how do i pass these values then **(levelnum:String, nextlevel:String)**

Comment: @djay Make them class variables perhaps.

Comment: @djay Updated using a global.

Comment: not working, not sure why. I even tried to remove everything in button's action and added only **println("button is working")** and i still got that error, weird :S

Comment: @djay Works for me. Are you sure your code's just like mine? Could you link to screen caps of your code?

Comment: @djay What's gamesubView?

Comment: thats where the main game is ,

Comment: @djay Oh, that's a problem. When the button's within `gameSubview` it's not able to recognize `buttonA:` since it's not within its class. Try moving the `func buttonA` method to `gameSubview`'s class.

Comment: i created gameSubview programmatically in GameviewController, so it doesn't have any class but i added that code in gameviewcontroller and still got that same error

Comment: @djay Could you post the code for gameSubview? I'm not sure I'm understanding your app structure...

Comment: @djay But how are you even accessing `gamesubView` from `LevelCompletedView`? You haven't nearly posted enough code from either class to diagnose this issue...

Comment: @djay That's because you haven't created an interface for GameViewController() before adding that subview.

Comment: i created gamesubView in UIViewController, so its accessible anywhere

Comment: ohhh how do i do that?

Comment: @djay I can't specify whether your passing in the proper view controller instance/how to pass in the proper view controller instance until I see more of your code.

Comment: hey it worked thanks, i copy pasted both the func's in Gameviewcontroller and it worked, i was creating a new class LevelCompletedView: because my GameVC has over 2000 lines of code and i thought i should separate everything, anyways may be i will stick with GameVC for now and will delete LevelCompletedView